# Float(s) lost when `todonotes` is used in a `longtable`

Tags: pdftex, errors, longtable, todonotes

As stated in the title, I'm trying to use `\todo{...}` on a `longtable`
MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|>{\arraybackslash}p{10cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Title}: Test table}\\
    \hline
    \endhead

    \hline
    \textbf{Column 1} & \lipsum[1]\\
    \hline 
    \textbf{Column 2} & \lipsum[2]\todo{test}\\
    \hline

    \caption{Table to test \texttt{todonotes}}\label{tab:test}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

When I compile the error I get is this:

```
LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.24 \end{document}
                   
You've lost some text.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

I do believe that this is due to some incompatibilities, but I'd like a second pair of eyes on this one.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: not really related to longtable, you can not use a marginpar in a box, use `\todo[inline]{test}`

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I use the `fixme` package instead, configured to use the `marginnote` package. Then a note can be added from anywhere with the added cost that they may overlap in the margin, but that is ok for me.

Comment: Both `todonotes` and `fixme` uses `\marginpar` by default and as a float there are limitations as to where they can be used.

Comment: Ok thank you guys! I write down the name of the package and check its documentation